# Creating an array in React and populating with values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to create an array and then populate it using a function. I'm basically working on a retirement calculator application and I have a couple of initial values including age, retirement age, salary, salary increase, contribution to savings, savings, and interest rate on savings which I'm getting through a form. Next using those values as a starting point I want to create a table which will show the salary, savings, increase, etc for each year starting from the user's starting age up until their retirement age. Similar to on this website https://www.bankrate.com/retirement/retirement-plan-calculator/.

So basically showing the yearly savings balance until retirement. My idea was to calculate these values and store it in an array and then map it onto a table. I'm very new to React and web programming in general so I honestly have no idea what I'm doing. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

```js
const Results = ({results}) => {

    var age = results.age;
    var retAge = results.retAge;
    //var yearsToRet = retAge - age;
    var salary = results.salary;
    var increase = results.increase;
    var cont = results.cont;
    var savings = results.savings;
    var interest = results.interest;
    var retSavings = savings;

    //To format the results as dollar value
    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {style: "currency", currency: "USD", minimumFractionDigits: 2})

    //Calculating savings during retirement
    for(var i = age; i < retAge; ++i)
    {
        //new salary with increase
        salary += salary * (increase/100);
        retSavings +=  salary*(cont/100) + retSavings*(interest/100); 
    }

    const savingsList = [
        {
            age: results.age,
            retAge: results.retAge,
            salary: results.salary,
            increase: results.increase,
            cont: results.cont,
            savings: results.savings,
            interest: results.interest,
            retSavings: savings,
        }
    ];
    console.log(savingsList);

    return(
        <><div className='results'>
            <h3> At retirement age of {retAge}, {results.name} will have a total savings of {formatter.format(retSavings)}</h3>
        </div></>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array? It seems that using an object and mapping it to a table would be a better option. Also I recommend using the useState and setState hooks, to manage your state. You could create a function that recalculated savings until retirement.

Comment: @StephanGuingor I guess I was trying to create an array since that's what I'm seeing online whenever I look up creating a table in React. My other thought is to use a function with a loop and populate the table with savings values until retirement. I'm still trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Use an array of objects to store the data. Right now you’re simply mutating the values in place and incrementing without actually storing the intermediate values anywhere.

Comment: @zmshah16 I think you're on the right track. You should use an array for table rows. What would your table column headings be?

Comment: @Benjamin For the table rows it would be age which I would also use as the table ID if it needs one, the age would start with the age prop and increment until the retirement age. Other headers would be the salary which would increase by a certain percentage with age, and last savings which will also be a calculated value

Comment: @Terry I'm just not sure how to do that yet. The current for loop is to find the savings at retirement age, but I was originally trying to get a value and put it in an array. I'm just learning React so I'm not familiar with creating arrays of objects in it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. For Table Row data, you will want to use an array. And you are right to use a loop to populate the array.

Here is how I would solve it.

First we loop over age, and push row data into the rows array.

Then we pass rows to a new component which I have named `ResultsTable`.

`ResultsTable` will then map over the rows and render another Component which I have named `ResultRow`.

`ResultRow` will then render the row data.

```js
import React from 'react';

export const Results = ({ results }) => {
  // Init an array for holding rows data
  const rows = [];

  // Initial variables
  let age = results.age;
  let salary = results.salary;
  let retSavings = results.savings;

  // Loop age until we reach retirement age, pushing data into the rows array
  while (age < results.retAge) {
    // Calculate the next salary and retSavings
    salary += salary * (results.increase / 100);
    retSavings += salary * (results.cont / 100) + retSavings * (results.interest / 100);

    // Push each row into the array
    rows.push({
      age: age,
      salary: salary,
      retSavings: retSavings,
    });

    ++age;
  }

  return (
    <div className="results">
      <h3>
        At retirement age of {results.retAge}, {results.name} will have a total savings of{' '}
        {formatCurrency(retSavings)}
      </h3>
      <ResultsTable rows={rows} />
    </div>
  );
};

const ResultsTable = ({ rows }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Age</td>
          <td>Salary</td>
          <td>Savings</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((row) => (
          <ResultRow key={row.age} data={row} />
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const ResultRow = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{data.age}</td>
      <td>{formatCurrency(data.salary)}</td>
      <td>{formatCurrency(data.retSavings)}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};

const formatCurrency = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
}).format;
```